# PDO with INSERT INTO

Tags: php, pdo, casting, insert, nvarchar

I want to make insert to MSSQL (miscorosft) database, but I have only option to use PHP (it would be a long story), so Iam trying the PDO.

The select queries are OK, but I got stuck on insert because the another system which is inserting the data use inserts like this `... VALUES ( CAST(N'2019-04-16 20:20:31.000' AS DateTime), N'4057415', N'False' ...` and Iam not sure, how and where (if its possible at all) can I use the N' and CAST with this:

```
$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO table1 (Date, Number, State) VALUES (?, ?,  ?)');
$data->execute(['2019-04-16 20:20:31.000', '4057415', 'False']);
```

Comment: Can you try with `'2019-04-16T20:20:31.000'` as datetime value? Thanks.

Comment: You mean without that CAST and N' ? Just like I have ´´´ $data->execute(['2019-04-16 20:20:31.000', '4057415', 'False']);  ´´´  ?

Comment: You should be able to just do this: `INSERT INTO table1 (Date, Number, State) VALUES (CAST(? AS DateTime), ?,  ?)`

Comment: @TomParis With `T` as a separator - `$data->execute(['2019-04-16T20:20:31.000', '4057415', 'False']);`.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting the `Date` value in the format `2019-05-28 12:52:16` - you can view an example with the PHP `date ("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

What's the error you are seeing when you attempt to insert a row?

Comment: I didnt tried it yet. Iam just not sure if there has to be the `CAST AS DateTime` or `N'` - I just saw from the DB export, that the inserts are like I mentioned and Iam just worried to send it without it.

Comment: You don't usually need to cast a value - PHP/MySQL are clever enough to work it out, and in cases where it can't you can explicitly define the type when binding params.  Casting a value inside a MySQL insert statement isn't the ideal way.